# Updating a field in structure - One to many mapping - Solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have a structure **Student** with one to many mapping and pushed values to it.Following is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

 struct Student{

  uint id;
  string name;
  uint256 mark;

 }

 mapping(uint => Student[]) StudentDetails;

function addStudent(uint classid,uint id,string name,uint256 mark) public payable{

     StudentDetails[classid].push(Student(id,name,mark));
  }
```

Now I need to update **mark** field without updating **id** and **name** for each student. How it can be done? Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: By the least give us the prototype of the function that you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer the following function -

```
function updateStudent(uint classid,uint studentindex,uint id,uint256 mark) public payable{

     StudentDetails[classid][studentindex].mark = mark;
  }
```

Hope it helps!